# How do I get my code to either display that the fileName is incorrect or the average of the numbers in the file?

Tags: c++

My code is supposed to ask for a file name, gets that file, then uses the numbers in it to calculate the average of the numbers. However, it instead shows the average as 0 and it also always displays both the error message and the average no matter if there was an error or not.

I have tried moving the if statement that checks if it failed or not to main so that it could end easily right there, and have tried using if statements to get it to end if there is an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

bool getFileName();
void display(float ave);
float readFile(char fileName[]);

int main()
{
   char fileName[256];
   float ave;
   getFileName();
   display(ave);
   return 0;
}


bool getFileName()
{ 
   char fileName[256];
   ifstream fin("file.txt");
   cout << "Please enter the filename: ";
   cin >> fileName;
   if (fin.fail())
   {
      cout << "Error reading file \"" << fileName << "\"" << endl; 
      return 0;
   }
   else
      return fileName;
} 


float readFile(char fileName[])
{
   char text[256];
   int i;
   ifstream fin("file.txt");
   int num;
   int total;

   for (fin >> text; i++;)
   {
      num += total;
   }
   fin.close();
   float ave = total / i;
   return ave;
}  


void display(float ave)
{
   cout << "Average Grade: " << ave << "%" << endl;
   return;
}
```

**Expected:**

```
Average Grade: (ave)%
```

OR

```
Error reading file "fileName"
```

**Actual:**

```
Error reading file "fileName"

Average Grade: (ave)%
```

Comment: Check `fin.is_open() == true` to see if the file was opened or not.

Comment: You should use the return value from `getFileName`. You should also fix it so that it returns boolean values rather than an `int` and a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modest alternative:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

std::string getFileName() {
    std::string fileName;
    std::cout << "Please enter the filename: ";
    std::cin >> fileName;
    return fileName;
}

double compute_average(std::string fileName) {
    std::ifstream fin(fileName);
    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unable to open file " + fileName);
    }

    int ct = 0;
    double total = 0.0l;

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(fin, line)) {
        double num = std::stod(line, nullptr);
        total += num;
        ct++;
    }
    fin.close();
    double ave = total / (double)ct;
    return ave;
}

void display(float ave) {
    std::cout << "Average Grade: " << ave << "%" << std::endl;
    return;
}

int main() {
    std::string fileName = getFileName();
    try {
        double ave = compute_average(fileName);
        display(ave);
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

NOTES:

1. It's often convenient to move "main()" to the bottom, before scrolling back up to look at the preceding code in more detail.
2. It's often useful to omit "using std", to see at a glace your dependencies.
3. You don't want to hard-code "file.txt". Certainly not in multiple places.
4. You do want to isolate file I/O to one place.
5. You want to prefer C++ "std::string" to C-style "char[]" arrays.
6. Added an example "try/catch" block

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not actually calling `readFile()` anywhere in the code. You simply pass `ave` (which is uninitialized) to `display()` which happens to display zero most of the time.
2. The return value of `getFileName()` is not assigned to anything, so the result is thrown away.